# How to get Selected Checkboxes form datatable using jquery

Tags: jquery, laravel-5, datatables, metronic

I'm using the metronic theme datatable and i want to get selected checkboxes values. This is the manage datatables from the metronic theme.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-checkable order-column" id="sample_1">
  <thead>
     <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th class="text-center"> User Name</th>
      <th class="text-center">Mobile</th>
      <th class="text-center">Email</th>
     </tr>
 </thead>
      @foreach($requests as $request)
         <tr class="odd gradeX text-center ">
           <td>
             <label class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-single mt-checkbox-outline">
                 <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes" value="{{$request->id}}" />
                   <span></span>
             </label>
           </td>
           <td>{{$request->name}}</td>
           <td>{{$request->mobile}}</td>
           <td>{{$request->email}}</td>
        </tr>
     @endforeach
```

Comment: you want to solve it using jquery then a selector $("input:checked") will give you all checboxes that are checked

Comment: How did it go? @Arslan Akram

Answer (score 1):

This solved my problem.

```
   var checkbox_value = [];
    var oTable = $('#sample_1').dataTable();
    var rowcollection =  oTable.$(".call-checkbox:checked", {"page": "all"});
    rowcollection.each(function(index,elem){
        checkbox_value.push($(elem).val());
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have jQuery in your tags, I am assuming that you can do this by the use of jQuery? In case of jQuery:

You can use the `:checked` selector to target your *checked* radio button.
In your case, you have a class to go by, so it will look something like:

`$(".checkboxes:checked").val();`

This will give you the value of the *checked* checkbox. You can also check to see if a certain checkbox is *checked* and return a boolean value by using `.is(":checked")`. That will return *true/false* depending on whether the checkbox is checked or not, and then you can construct a logic from that.

You can also make a checkbox be *checked* by using either:

`$(".checkboxes").attr('checked', true);`

or,

`$(".checkboxes").prop('checked');`

Note that I am using your `.checkboxes` class, since that's what you have to target in your example. Note that a class is usually something you will have repeated instances of (not in your example, but generally speaking). So these examples will target all instances having that class. If you want to target a specific element, use *id* instead, i.e `$("#....")`.

Hope this helped. :)